# Wordpress post-formats export/import for register_post_type

Tags: wordpress

I created portfolio using `register_post_type` with `'support' => 'post-formats'` and everything works fine (create, edit, etc.). But when I try to export/import wordpress xml the only thing that didn't export/import is post-formats of the portfolio.
I opened xml file and for posts there is lines: `<category domain="post_format" nicename="post-format-audio"><![CDATA[Audio]]></category>`
but not for portfolio types.

Comment: Have you finally found a solution about this?

If yes, can you help share it :)
I'm facing this problem too.

Answer (score 1):

This questions is one year ago and you may not need the answer anymore.

However, I finally found the answer.

After spending time debugging export.php, I found that we have to register post_format taxonomy for our custom post type.

```
register_taxonomy( 'post_format', 'portfolio', array(
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'labels' => array(
                    'name' => _x( 'Format', 'post format' ),
                    'singular_name' => _x( 'Format', 'post format' ),
            ),
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => $rewrite['post_format'],
            'show_ui' => false,
            '_builtin' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => current_theme_supports( 'post-formats' ),
    ) );
```

Easy as that!

Comment: I can't get this to work for my custom post type... has anything changed with this approach?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out... So just a bit of clarification to your answer (although this may seem obvious to some): **make sure you register this in the same action hook function as where you register your post type** so that you don't get caught out by timing issues. E.g. if you register your post type in a function hooked to the 'init' action, make sure you register this taxonomy there too ;)